# n-channel MOSFET source load alternative

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, mosfet, pwm

[image: Case 1]

I'm trying to drive some RBG leds using MOSFETS. Let's say I have 2 individually RBG LEDS, each controlled by 12V, with each R, B and G with its own output to GND. What I want to control, is to be able to turn each LED on/off. I'm using 4 MOSFETS for each LED: One for 12V ON/OFF and the remaining for each R, B and G PWM control. The second MOSFET is used by all RBG's, so they are running at the same PWM. I'm only interessted in controlling an ON/OFF state of each LED.

So my first thought was to use the case 1 combined with case 3, where the load in case 1 would be the 12V from the diode. However, from what I read, and also by experiment, in the case 1 the gate is always open. Using case 2 would solve this case, but my current problem is, that I only have N-channel mosfets available. So I'm looking for a possible workaround, so I don't have to wait another month for some P-channel mosfets.

My question is then, is there any safe and easy workaround? My LED Strips are running at approximately 400 mA/meter, so in the case of. e.g. 5 RBG Led's, a max current of 2A per channel is required.

My attempt to a solution schematic can be seen below.
[image: Solution]

Comment: Your schematic incomplete, however I will mention that to use an N-channel MOSFET as the high-side driver, you will need to drive the gate at greater than 12V.

Comment: Why not just turn off all three low-side drivers to turn off the LED, and skip the high-side driver?

Comment: #Tut as I'm controlling it from an MCU, this would not be a possible solution :)

If I turn all three lower drivers off, it would also affect the remaining LED's I want to only change the ON/OFF state of  one LED at a time.

Comment: So you are controlling the RGB lines with a ON/OFF signal and the fourth MOSFET with a PWM driver?

Comment: #sherrellbc sorry if I have been a bit unclear.

The RBG is each controlled by a PWM Driver. It is only the input signal, VCC, that I wish to control with an ON/OFF state.  

If the first MOSFET (ON/OFF) is on, the LED is controlled by the PWM drivers of the RBG MOSFETS. If it's OFF for that specific LED, all of the three RBG LEDS for that specific LED is off.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this should work for you, and the LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh5wx6sf56qdgnu/NMOS%20LED%20switch.asc) if you want to play with the circuit

[image]

Comment: #EM Fields thanks for your answer. 

It does seem like a possible solution, however let's say I have 5 pair of RBG LEDs. Wouldn't it then require me to have 5 MOSFETS for each RBG LED ? All of the RBG LEDs have to be connected to the same PWM driver, but only the ON/OFF state is the on I wish to control :)

Comment: You don't need both Q4 and Q5.

Comment: user: I'm confused. You mention individual R,G, and B LEDs, then LED strips with, ostensibly, a common 12V supply and separate grounds for each of the internal R, G, and B strings, and then pairs of RBG LEDs.  Can you supply a little more detail or, better yet, schematic showing the LED configuration(s), please?

Comment: Mike: Right you are, but Q5 would be nice to have since he can't/doesn't want to turn off the +12 with a P MOSFET.